# getting monthly data for specific months based on SYSDATE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am running a query on a monthly basis to select 
data on the basis of months JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,SEP
OCT,NOV,DEC.

Lets say i am running this query in FEB 2018, then the data
of JAN and FEB should come from current year(2018) and data from MAR,APR,SEP
OCT,NOV,DEC should come from previous year(2017). How do i handle this with SYSDATE.

```
>SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MONTH_NAME 
IN ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC') 
AND 
YEAR=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'YYYY');
```

Assuming i have columns MONTH_NAME having all month names and YEAR with year to match the record.

Comment: Please, tell the rules in what cases you need data only from current year, and when from previous and current.

Comment: Also add some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data it's hard to tell what exactly you want, but it could be something like this.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM   my_table 
WHERE  month_name IN ( 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 
                       'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC' ) 

AND ( 
      ( EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM TO_DATE( month_name ,'MON' ) ) 
                    <= EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM SYSDATE ) AND YEAR = 2018) OR
      ( EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM TO_DATE( month_name ,'MON' ) ) 
                  >  EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM SYSDATE ) AND YEAR = 2017)
    )
```

Preferably add  `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH'` as 3rd argument of `TO_DATE`

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample data I'd suggest the following approach:

- obtain the list of required dates

```
select  add_months(
            trunc(sysdate,'mm'),
            - level + 1
        )
  from  dual
connect by level <= 12;
```

this query will return first days of last 11 months and the currenct month

- then join the results of this query to your table